# Why is undefined == undefined but NaN != NaN?

Tags: javascript

I am wondering why `undefined == undefined` but `NaN != NaN`.

Comment: because `typeof NaN == "number"`

Comment: This is *not* an exact duplicate of the linked question. Not by any stretch of the imagination.

Comment: People: This is not about null; it's about NaN. This is the most *inexact* duplicate I've ever seen.

Comment: @Skilldrick, the question is *why* the equality is the way it is, which I took to be the same underlying question.

Comment: @zzzzBov The question as I take it is about why `NaN` is not equal to `NaN`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because that's how it is defined in both the [Abstract Equality Comparison Algorithm](http://es5.github.com/#x11.9.3), and the [Strict Equality Comparison Algorithm](http://es5.github.com/#x11.9.6).

If either operand to `==` or `===` is `NaN`, it returns `false`.

**Abstract**

> - If Type(x) is Number, then
>
>   - If x is NaN, return false.
>   - If y is NaN, return false.
>   - If x is the same Number value as y, return true.
>   - If x is +0 and y is −0, return true.
>   - If x is −0 and y is +0, return true.
>   - Return false.

---

**EDIT:** The motivation for the unequal comparison as noted by [@CMS](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5445/cms) is compliance with the IEEE 754 standard.

From the Wikipedia link provided in the comment below:

> ...The normal comparison operations however treat NaNs as unordered and compare −0 and +0 as equal. The totalOrder predicate will order these cases, and *it also distinguishes between different representations of NaNs* and between the same decimal floating point number encoded in different ways.

Comment: And it is defined in this way, in the two Equality Algorithms just because the specification is conforming with the rules of the [IEEE 754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) Standard for the Number type.

Comment: Thanks @CMS. I'll update my answer with the information you provided.

Answer (score 4):

Because `Math.sqrt(-5) !== Math.sqrt(-6)`.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why it is like this, but in order to check if a certain statement or variable is a NaN, you should use the [isNaN](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_isNaN.asp) method

Answer (score 0):

I would assume because the IEEE standard allows for more than one representation of NaN.  Not all NaNs are equal to each other...

Comment: According to the ECMAScript spec, all NaN values are indistinguishable from each other (although admittedly, implementations can differ): http://es5.github.com/#x8.5

Comment: I don't believe that being indistinguishable is enough to establish equality.  Any logicians on here know for sure?

Comment: It's the opposite: Being able to be equal to some but not others would make them distinguishable. Either they must all be equal or they must all by unequal if they are to be indistinguishable.

Answer (score -1):

The reasoning is that the creators wanted `x == x` returning false to mean that x is NaN, so NaN == NaN has to return false to be consistent.