# Why does the Math.round(float f) method in Android check for NaN?

Tags: java, android

I was looking at the `Math` sources in the Android Framework and here is what the `round()` method looks like :

```
public static int round(float f) {
    // check for NaN
    if (f != f) {
        return 0;
    }
    return (int) floor(f + 0.5f);
}
```

I'm trying to wrap my head around what the first check does without success. How could f be different from itself ? I also can't think of any test case that would make this any different... Any idea ?

Comment: See [JLS 15.21.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.21.1).  That's just how it's defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How could f be different from itself?

If `f` is a NaN it will test as different from all floats including another NaN. That's the definition. From [JLS #15.21.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.21.1):

> "If either operand is NaN, then the result of == is false but the result of != is true. Indeed, the test x!=x is true if and only if the value of x is NaN."

> I also can't think of any test case that would make this any different... Any idea?

Err, `Float.NaN.`

Comment: I find this a bit confusing but I guess it makes sense. Thanks EJP, will mark the answer as accepted when possible

Answer (score 0):

NaN is the only variable for which `x != x` holds true. Take a look at [this answer for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8819738/why-does-double-nan-double-nan-return-false).

Comment: Thanks! This thread definitely made it easier for me to understand the reason why it's how it works