# System.out.println(0.0%0.0!=0.0/0.0); what will be the out put ? Can you Please Explain the Answers any one?

Tags: java

I was just studying OCJP questions and I found this strange code:

```
public class abc {
    public static void main(String[] args) {


        System.out.println(0.0%0.0!=0.0/0.0);// it return true

        System.out.println(0.0%0.0==0.0/0.0);// it return false


    }

}
```

When I ran the code, I got:

```
true
false
```

How is the output false when we're comparing two things that look the same as each other? What does NaN mean?

Comment: They don't look the same to me at all. Or rather, they look about as same as `3/4` as `3**4`

Comment: Why do you think the equality should be true?

Answer (score 2):

Both `0.0 / 0.0` and `0.0 % 0.0` return `Double.NaN`.

If you compare `Double.NaN == Double.NaN` you will receive `false` and this is why `System.out.println(0.0%0.0==0.0/0.0);` prints `false`.

The question now goes to why does `Double.NaN == Double.NaN` return `false`?

According to JLS:

> Floating-point operators produce no exceptions (§11). An operation
>   that overflows produces a signed infinity, an operation that
>   underflows produces a denormalized value or a signed zero, and an
>   operation that has no mathematically definite result produces NaN. All
>   numeric operations with NaN as an operand produce NaN as a result. As
>   has already been described, NaN is unordered, so a numeric comparison
>   operation involving one or two NaNs returns false and any !=
>   comparison involving NaN returns true, including x!=x when x is NaN.

More info:

- [Why does Double.NaN==Double.NaN return false?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8819738/why-does-double-nan-double-nan-return-false)

Comment: Interstingly, the byte code is  :                                      0:   getstatic       #16; //Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
   **3:   iconst_1**
   4:   invokevirtual   #22; //Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Z)V
   7:   getstatic       #16; //Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
   **10:  iconst_0**
   11:  invokevirtual   #22; //Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Z)V
   14:  return ... I don't understand why `0` and `1` are being loaded onto the stack here .