# Comparing NaN in Kotlin

Tags: floating-point, nan, kotlin

So I recently started loving the language kotlin. Today, while comparing doubles, I came across the inevitable `NaN`.

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val nan = Double.NaN
    println("1: " + (nan == nan))
    println("2: " + (nan == (nan as Number)))
    println("3: " + ((nan as Number) == nan))
}
```

*N.B: (*`Double` *is a subtype of* [`Number`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-number/)*)*

Running the above code yields:

```
1: false
2: true
3: true
```

I understand that [comparing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8819738/why-does-double-nan-double-nan-return-false/8820592#8820592) with `NaN` in Java returns `false`, so I would expect `false` for all expressions.

How can this behavior be explained?
What is the rationale behind it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That's because **(2)** and **(3)** are compiled to boxing a primitive and then `Double.equals` check: on JVM, primitive `double` can't be compared to a boxed one.

[`Double.equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#equals(java.lang.Object)), in turn, checks equality by comparing [`doubleToLongBits(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#doubleToLongBits(double)) of the two `Double`s, and for the latter there's a guarantee that

> If the argument is NaN, the result is `0x7ff8000000000000L`.

So, the bits returned for two `NaN` are equal, and the rule `NaN != NaN` is ignored here.

Also, as **@miensol** mentioned, there's another consequence of this equality check: `+0` and `-0` are equal according to `==` check and not to `equals` check.

Equivalent code in Java would be:

```
double nan = Double.NaN;
System.out.println("1: " + (nan == nan)) //false 
System.out.println("2: " + ((Double) nan).equals(((Number) nan)))
System.out.println("3: " + ((Number) nan).equals(nan));
```

The last two lines call `Double.equals`, comparing `doubleToLongBits(...)`.

Comment: @nrohwer, thanks for your remark, updated the answer.

Answer (score 8):

The first comparison is equivalent to Java's:

```
double left = Double.NaN;
double right = Double.NaN;
boolean result = left == right;
```

And as you can [read in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8819738/why-does-double-nan-double-nan-return-false) this is standarized and documented behavior.

The second & third comparison are equivalent to:

```
Double left = Double.valueOf(Double.NaN);
Number right = Double.valueOf(Double.NaN);
boolean result = left.equals(right);
```

Which uses [Double.equals](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#equals(java.lang.Object)):

> Note that in most cases, for two instances of `class Double`, `d1` and `d2`,
>   the value of `d1.equals(d2)` is true if and only if `d1.doubleValue() ==
>   d2.doubleValue()` also has the value true. However, there are two
>   exceptions:
>
> - If `d1` and `d2` both represent `Double.NaN`, then the equals
>     method returns `true`, even though `Double.NaN==Double.NaN` has the value
>     `false`.
> - If `d1` represents `+0.0` while `d2` represents `-0.0`, or vice versa,
>     the equal test has the value `false`, even though `+0.0==-0.0` has the
>     value `true`.