# Missing concept based on Not a Number (NaN)

Tags: javascript

It's JavaScript Code (used Console) and have a small doubt on this code

```
var foo = 10;
var boo = undefined;

if((foo + boo)==NaN){console.log("Not a Number !!!");}
//>undefined
if((foo + boo)===NaN){console.log("Not a Number !!!");}
//>undefined

//>Not a Number !!!    (Expected)
```

Comment: use `isNan()` function to check if is NaN

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: and (maybe) [Why is undefined == undefined but NaN != NaN?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7178175/218196)

Comment: I have compared NaN with undefined.

Comment: No you haven't. `10 + undefined` results in `NaN`. You have compared `NaN == NaN` and `NaN === NaN`.

Comment: I have compared results of 'undefined' with 'NaN' i.e 'undefined == undefined' then true, similarly 'NaN == NaN' would be true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Equality operator (== and ===) cannot be used to test a value against
>   NaN. Use Number.isNaN() or isNaN() instead.
>
> ```
> NaN === NaN;        // false
> Number.NaN === NaN; // false
> isNaN(NaN);         // true
> isNaN(Number.NaN);  // true
> ```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN

Answer (score 1):

See below URL to fix your Issue....

[JavaScript isNaN() Function](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_isnan.asp)

Check whether a number is an illegal number:

```
var a = isNaN(123) + "<br>";
var b = isNaN(-1.23) + "<br>";
var c = isNaN(5-2) + "<br>";
var d = isNaN(0) + "<br>";
var e = isNaN("Hello") + "<br>";
var f = isNaN("2005/12/12") + "<br>";
```

The result of res will be:

```
 false
 false
 false
 false
 true
 true
```

Comment: This isn't an answer. This is just a link and if the link dies, this post is useless. Answers should be self contained. Please include the actual information in your post. Linking to external content *in addition* is perfectly fine. Aside from that, the information given at w3schools is not correct (oh wonder!) or at least confusing: `isNaN` doesn't check whether a value is an "illegal number" (whatever that is), it checks whether the value is `NaN`, which actually is a very special number value.

Comment: @FelixKling Thank you for your kind of suggestion...

Comment: You should get into the habit to refer to the MDN documentation (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN), rather than w3schools. For why, see http://www.w3fools.com/.